# Synonym for 'little bits'

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I have recently been undertaking some document review and updated a sentence to the following which seemed correct to me at the time.

> The New Starter will be given a Training Record folder, a USB stick of
> information and an assortment of stationery and other **errata**.

Now, the definition of errata does not fit the usage here:

> plural noun: errata an error in printing or writing. a list of
> corrected errors appended to a book or published in a subsequent issue
> of a journal.

I want a single word to cover the collection of the other odd bits and bobs which someone may be given outside of those listed. I imagine the word I am actually looking for is fairly closely related and I have erroneously substituted it, but I can't think of it. I have tried looking for synonyms of `things` and `stuff` online so far to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We call that *swag* round here. But *ephemera* might be what you're looking for:

> **ephemera**
> *plural noun*
>
> 1 Things that exist or are used or enjoyed for only a short time.
>
> *‘Load up on cool ephemera and tacky souvenirs: NYPD snow domes, stick-on bullet holes, match books, carrier bags, free postcards,
> anything that says I heart NY.’*
>
> <sub>Source: [Lexico —
> *ephemera*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ephemera)</sub>

Comment: Yes, that's the word I was looking for. Of course, now that this has been recalled, I actually prefer sundries and will use that, but nice to get the answer...

Answer (score 4):

How about ***sundries***?

> : various items not important enough to be mentioned individually.
>
> ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sundry#:%7E:text=nounplural%20noun%20sundries,enough%20to%20be%20mentioned%20individually.))

> : miscellaneous small articles, details, or items
>
> ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sundries))

> The New Starter will be given a Training Record folder, a USB stick of information and an assortment of stationery and other *sundries*.

---

There's also ***odds and ends*** (although not a single word):

> : various things of different types, usually small and not important, or of little value
>
> ([Collins Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/odds-and-ends))

> The New Starter will be given a Training Record folder, a USB stick of information and an assortment of stationery and other *odds and ends*.

Comment: Sundries definitely fits what I was thinking of. If no other better alternatives arrive I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

**miscellany** (n.)

> A group or collection of different items; a mixture.
>
> *Next comes a corridor where a miscellany of drawings, a small but exquisite textile and two engraved gems, one of Lorenzo the
> Magnificent and one of Savonarola, are displayed.*
>
> *Curry House serves about 14 kinds of curry using a miscellany of
> ingredients, among them chicken, pork, beef and peeled shrimp.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/miscellany)

> A miscellany of things is a collection or group of many different
> kinds of things. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/miscellany)

---

> Two up-to-date department stores, the one modern hotel, the leading
> motion picture house, and a **miscellany** of smaller shops and
> restaurants give the feeling of a shopping area. [Federal Writer's
> Project of the Works Progress Administration for the State of N.J.;
> *New Jersey, a Guide to Its Present and Past*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_Jersey_a_Guide_to_Its_Present_and_Pa/t6wmzEJvTGcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22and%20a%20miscellany%20of%22&pg=PA351&printsec=frontcover) (2007)

> In addition to their load of passengers, aircraft bound for the South
> American countries carried express equaling several hundred tons in
> weight — clothing, gold and silver bullion, chickens, drugs, jewelry,
> films, and a **miscellany** of articles too numerous to mention. [*Can
> the United States Retain Latin American Trade and Cultural Relations Against
> German, Italian, and Japanese Competition?*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Can_the_United_States_Retain_Latin_Ameri/DbwLAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22and%20a%20miscellany%20of%22&dq=%22and%20a%20miscellany%20of%22&printsec=frontcover) (1939)